# Random 'active' nav-tab (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make my Bootstrap 'nav-tabs' tab be dynamic and randomize the active one on document load (everytime site loads)?

I have the following schema:
https://www.bootply.com/scKyFxqsNG

Thanks

Comment: @SilverSurfer sorry, my bad. I need the randomize everytime that page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //Generate random number

  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

  //Select `li` at random and add a class

  $("#home-tabs-menu li").eq(rand).addClass('active');

  // Select `li a` at random and use .show();

  $("#home-tabs-menu li a").eq(rand).show();

});
```

Comment: If you have a max of 3 then it should be 2. `eq()` starts at 0.

Comment: @BrunoMosciattiG.Maciel Actually, no, you were right. Yes, make it 3.

Comment: it works... but I need to give .show() each 'li a' randomed, how can I take it?

Comment: @BrunoMosciattiG.Maciel See my updated code. It will use `show()` on a random element.

Answer (score 0):

On every load, use javascript random to get a number and set the active class depending on the result

```
 var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1  
 if(i == 1)
 $("#tab1").addClass(".active")
```